Special case of Ramanujan's theta function.
$\textbf{Reference:}$ "Number Theory in the Spirit of Ramanujan."
I started reading this book last week. I'd like to know whether my proof needs more clarity or if it is enough.
One of the special case of Ramanujan's theta function is:
$$\psi(q):=f(q,q^3)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} q^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$$
$\textbf{Proof:}$
$f(q,q^3)= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} q^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}q^{\frac{3n(n-1)}{2}}= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} q^{n(2n-1)}= \sum_{n=-1}^{-\infty} q^{n(2n-1)} +\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} q^{n(2n-1)}$
$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} q^{n(2n+1)} +\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} q^{n(2n-1)}   \text{(we get this by replacing $n$ by $-n$ in first infinite sum in above expression).}$
$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} q^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$
as the power $n(2n+1)$ represent the sum of first $n$ positive even integers (including $0$) and the power $n(2n-1)$ represent the sum of first $n$ positive odd integers. That complete the proof!

Proof is correct &  all operations holds within convergence of a series

@Guruprasad thank you!
